# Testing for regional interaction effects using a hierarchical model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, hierarchical-data, regional

I want to test for voters' motives behind castig one's vote for a given party 'XY' and whether residence in a region makes a significant difference. The question is, do voters from region A (coded '1') significantly differ in their motives from voters in region B (coded '0').

Here is how my data are structured (over-simplified):

```
region_AB   motive   voter_attribute  vote_for_party_XY
1           1        1                1
1           0        1                1
1           1        0                0
0           0        0                0
0           0        1                0
0           1        0                0
```

My guess would be to run a binary logistic, hierarchical model in R but then how would I find out whether different motives and voter characteristics play a role for citizens in region A and B? I Don't simply want to test for regional effects but for the difference region makes within the overall model.

Or can I simply throw interaction terms in a standard logistic regression model (e.g. `region*motive1`, `region*motive2`...)?

But in that case, how many interaction terms can I add? Would I have to recode the zeros in 'region' into something like `0.0000000001` as multiplication with zero would distort the results? Lastly, would I have to throw the interaction terms into the model alongside the two components of this interaction term (e.g. `region`, `motive`, and `region*motive`) or would this only result in multicollinearity?

Thank you!

Comment: Hope I'm not duplicating anything, but I've done some research and haven't found a question exactly like mine, let alone a solution to my exact questions. Even if there is one which I have overlooked, maybe there are some aspects about my problem that would make it interesting to others... :-)

Comment: This is more of a statistics question than a programming question. You probably would get a better response on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)  the statistics site.

Comment: It's at the boundary between on-topic in SO and CrossValidated.com. The CV rules say that questions of the form: `How to do X in language Y?` are off-topic. The last part of the question has an R-specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outcome is binary, so the natural modeling framework would be logistic regression. I do not see a hierarchal structure to the data gathering, so would simply recommend using an interaction term formed between region and motivation using the `*`-operator.

```
 glm( vote_for_party_XY ~ region_AB * motive +  voter_attribute, family = "binomial")
```

Note that the R formula interface includes both "main effect" terms when the "*" operator is used. You get the same effect with:

```
 region_AB + motive + region_AB : motive
```

There will be (at least) three coefficients describing the region-motivation results: one for region alone (applicable to persons in region==1 and motivation=0), a second for motivation alone( applicable to persons in region 0, and motivation=1) and a third (for those persons with both region=1 and motivation=1). All estimates will be relative to an intercept term that applies to persons with all factors at the 0-(reference) level. To calculate voting rates for persons with region=1 and region=1, you add coefficients for Intercept, region=1 and the interaction coefficient. If there are more than two levels of 'region' (say n) and 'motivation' (say m) the number of coefficients will be `1 +(n-1) +(m-1)+(n-1)*(m-1)` , which I think comes out to `n*m` (including Intercept).

Comment: Thank you! Just to get it right:

1.) I can include as many interaction terms as I need without this affecting my model or anything. Correct? 
For example: (... ~ `regionAB`*`motive1` + `regionAB`*`motive2` + `regionAB`*`attribute1`...)

2.) Should I recode the zeros in my binary `regionAB` to `0.00001` so as not to distort the results? Otherwise, I would implicitly assume that the effect of `motiveXY` is null when voters are in region B, but gets even more intense when voters are in region A. Right?

Comment: 3.) Based on what can you say that my data are non-hierarchical? My region variable could as well be different schools and school classes from the famous hierarchical-data textbooks, right? In this case it's aggregated German Bundesländer: East/West.

Comment: I would need to see how the data is coded. If an individual can have more than 1 "motive" then perhaps yes to 1. If motives are "one per customer" then no. To 2 i'd say probably not.  0 is just a level of a discrete variable. In R region should be a factor.

Comment: The second comment (labeled 3) is not a coding question, but  rather a "methodological" question. You already have my opinion based on a very sketchy description of the data and research goals that this did not appear hierarchal. If you left out significant material in your question,  then the answer may not be applicable, and a more statistically focussed question on CV.com may be warranted. Not all interaction models qualify as hierarchal in my view.

Comment: Ad 1. Yes, individuals can have multiple motives and attributes in this case. Think of common voter analyses: An individual may be poor, well-educated, female, politically interested, based in region B, and a voter of party XY.

Ad 2. That makes sense, thank you again. I will go with a number of interaction terms then and see what I get.

Ad 3. Sure, that was a mahor excursion to methodological questions. Yet, my understanding of hiearchical models is that you need to have a context factor that may affect `X-->Y` in some way and that may be regions, districts, schools, classes, etc.

Comment: If the sampling was based on regions then yes, but if the inference is to be applied to voters and to have a random sample of voters then it’s not hierarchal in my understanding.